# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on laptop with GTX 1070

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, dual-boot

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as a dual boot on my Alienware 15 R3 by following [this document](https://github.com/awesomebytes/alienware15r3_ubuntu14).

However, when I boot Ubuntu from live USB (which means "Try Ubuntu without Installing"), Ubuntu gets low graphics mode and can't go further.

I think this might be related to graphic card (GTX1070). Ubuntu 14.04 Live ISO cannot deal with GTX 1070, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

When I tried Ubuntu 16.04 instead, it successfully worked but I need 14.04 LTS.

Do you have any idea?

My Alienware 15 R3 is:

- CPU: Intel R Core i7-7820HK
- GPU: GTX1070 8GB
- Memory: 16GB DDR4 2400MHz (2x8GB)
- Hard disk: 256GB SSD+ 1TB HDD

Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters use something newer, the current 17.10 or the LTS 16.04 (16.04.3) and forget about outdated guides. You may need `nomodeset` also until the Nvidia drivers are installed and that is absent in the PoS confusing guide you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu 16.04 works OK on your laptop, install that and run Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox if you need it. Ubuntu 14.04 will run well in VirtualBox if you allocate 2 processor cores and at least 4GB of base memory in the guest OS settings. The downside is that VirtualBox cannot use your Nvidia GTX 1070 graphics card unless PCI passthrough is supported in VirtualBox for your computer's hardware. If your laptop's hardware does not support PCI passthrough, you are restricted to a maximum of 256MB video memory which is virtual too.